# Does "see" means taking some action in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-choice

> So far, the inauguration of a ‘Tripartite Agglomeration Conference’ is
> an interesting innovation because it brings together all three federal
> levels in order to deliberate on common problems. A stronger
> institution-building could follow two courses. Either cantons and
> communes will **see** a revitalisation of historical districts, , with the
> advantage that the old geographical patterns of common political
> culture can be utilised. Or the consolidation of urban government will
> be achieved by the statutory creation of a special region. Urban
> regions can be designed to effectively cover effectively the common
> entire geographic range of public goods. Yet people may consider them
> artificial because their boundaries do not represent patterns of
> common political culture or reflect a sense of political community. If
> both ways are unsatisfactory, a third option may be considered. It
> consists of a flexible organisation in which just those communes
> cooperate who are willing to share part of their facilities and public
> services. Prices for common public services are higher for non-members
> than for members. This organisation helps to restrict the benefits of
> cooperation to members and creates incentives for initial non-members
> to join (Arbeitsgruppe 1992; Lehmann et al. 2003).
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Linder Mueller*

According to Cambridge Dictionary the word "see" have several meanings:

1. to be conscious of what is around you by using your eyes:
2. to be the time or place when something happens:
3. to understand, know, or realize:
4. to consider or think about, especially to think about someone or something in a particular way, or to imagine someone doing a particular activity:

I am confused. Because the writes here talks about creating something (institution-building). But seeing something means that you have no influence to occurings.
What does see means in this context? Does Cantons and Communes have an influence on ongoing events or they just "seeing" them?

Comment: could it mean "they ensure that the revitalisation will happen"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"see" here means "experience". Specifically, "cantons and communes will see a revitalisation of historical districts" means that historical districts in cantons and communes will be revitalized.

More fully the text says that **either** this revitalisation wil occur, **or else** consolidation of urban government will be achieved.

This is closest to meaning 2 of "see" that is "to be the time or place when something happens:" because the cantons and communes will be there when the revitalisation  occurs. But see, especially in a future tense, is often used for "expericne" For example.

- > The 2020s will see the increasing dominance of electronic shopping.
- > The Netherlands saw one of the greatest lad reclamation projects ever undertaken.
- > World War II saw the culmination and refinement of mass warfare.
- > You will see a vast improvement of medical technology in your lifetime.

In this usage "see" is metaphorical, it is often applied to things, like a time period, that have no power of vision.